# How to get access between a database and a mobile app that are not on the same network?

Tags: database

How will I be able to connect my app with a database that is on other network and private (maybe)? I have tried to connect my app with the database found on the same network and it works but not when my app is on another network. How to solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to open at least the specific database (TCP) port (e.g. in the firewall) for both hosts and a routing between the networks should be existent.

Comment: Thanks for responding but for example, if I am in a big enterprise and the databases are private as well. How will I make my app accessible to the databases in order to perform like Login, Register and so on? And, I want to make an app that will available to many users as well. That is, I am at location X with my mobile and I want to access the database Y from a different location. Hope you can enlighten me, thank you.

Comment: Within an app you can also display websites. You can open the port for the webserver (for all) and the webserver connects locally to the database and does the work for the app. You have to give more detailled information what your architecture looks like.

Comment: Can you tell me what steps that I should perform and any programming codes ? The architecture is that all mobile apps can get access to that private database, just like the Facebook database, means facebook database holds username and passwords and if ever someone wants to login, he actually can no matter where he/she is. In your view what is ideal to be done to allow any mobile app to get access to that database??? Should it be associated to a web service and then the database?